# How to Read a Map from Firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read data from *Firestore* into my TypeScript Project.

In *Firestore* I have a Map under the field `mapName`

The following data structure I got while using `JSON.stringify(change.after.data())`

```
const test: Test = {
  mapName: {
    "v3mioXc3VoFgfj0WEq": {
      isNormalSubscription: false,
    },
    "as12oXc3VoFas12WEq": {
      isNormalSubscription: true,
    },
  },
};

interface Test {
  mapName: Map<string, any>
}
```

I am getting though the following error:

```
Type '{ v3mioXc3VoFgfj0WEq: { isNormalSubscription: false; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, any>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"v3mioXc3VoFgfj0WEq"' does not exist in type 'Map<string, any>'.
```

Since `v3mioXc3VoFgfj0WEq` and `as12oXc3VoFas12WEq` are Firestore Keys that I do not know beforehand, how should I change my Test interface to properly manage the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not accept or return ES6 `Map` type object.  It only works with plain old JavaScript objects.  When you call `data()` on a `DocumentSnapshot`, you get one of these plain objects.  The properties of the object match the fields in the document.

```
const obj = snapshot.data()   // plain object
const mapName = obj.mapName   // another plain object
const field1 = mapName.v3mioXc3VoFgfj0WEq
const field2 = mapName.as12oXc3VoFas12WEq
```

If you would rather work with a `Map` object, you will have to convert the plain object into a new Map.

Comment: I would like to iterate through the mapName field without knowing the "keys". If I got this right from your above code, is this not possible?

Comment: That's a different question (iterating properties of an object), and it has lots of different answers already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: I did not know that I could just iterate through this data structure. I had in mind that I should have an array structure for that. This helped.

Comment: How to define the interface for a map?